# Kubundu 20.04 switching between Intel and Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, optimus, tearing

I just did a clean install of Kubuntu 20.04 (was previously running Kubuntu 19.10) on my "PC Specialist Defiance 2" laptop, which is a rebranded Clevo:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep -iA9 'system info'
System Information
        Manufacturer: PC Specialist Limited
        Product Name: P65_P67RGRERA
        Version: Not Applicable                  
        Serial Number: Not Applicable                  
        UUID: 275bfa80-a763-0000-0000-000000000000
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: Not Applicable                  
        Family: Not Applicable
```

Unfortunately I cannot *cleanly* switch between using the Intel GPU and Nvidia GPU. On 19.10, I used to be able to simply:

```
$ prime-select [nvidia|intel]
```

and then reboot. While this still *kind of works* in Kubuntu 20.04, switching to the Nvidia GPU results in tearing. To get rid of the tearing, I created `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-tearing.conf` with:

```
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

I then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot, and this solves the tearing issue when using the Nvidia GPU. However, when I switch back to the Intel GPU, my laptop freezes during boot. To get around this, I have comment out the above line in `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-tearing.conf` and then do a `sudo update-initramfs -u` (and then reboot again).

Is there any way to only run the `nvidia-drm modeset=1` option when in Nvidia GPU mode?